# Force "admin" session for admin accounts on RDP Servers

Tags: windows-server

is there a way to enforce the special admin session that can be triggered with /admin on the client from the server as well?

It would be kinda annoying especially, as mstsc doesn't expose the switch in the GUI, if a slight carelessness can cause another RDS CAL to be taken away, therefore it would be nice to have a way to name user accounts that cannnot connect to any of the "RDS" Session but rather the "admin" sessions.

Comment: Other than creating a .rdp file with the server adress baked in already, nope. Maybe an alternate client which is basically the same thing...

Comment: The only way to connect to "admin" session is use RDS admin mode (mstsc /admin). With remote desktop services installed on the server, there is no way to force "admin" session for accounts. When you use mstsc (not admin mode) to connect, even admin accounts need cals for connection.

Comment: @Seven okay thought so, frankly this is a little annoying that you cannot enforce this on the server especially since the admin option is easy to miss, as I doubt many people open mstsc via commandline